# Rspec stub array of classes

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have a loop like this defined:

```
 api.release(release_url).rels[:assets].get.data.each do |existing_file|
   log "Already Contains: #{existing_file.name}"
 end
```

How can I stub `existing_file.name`? I want it give it multiple values as well.

I tried to stub it like this:

```
      provider.api.release.rels[:assets].get.stub(:data).and_return([{ :name => "foo.bar"}, { :name => "bar.foo"])
```

But this returns the error: `undefined method 'name' for Hash`. This makes me think that I am iterating through a array of classes. Any advice on how to stub this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It may be far too late, but you might want to google "Dependency Injection".

Comment: Also [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`double`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs) - you should do something like this:

```
provider.api.release.rels[:assets].get.stub(:data).and_return(
  [double(:name => "foo.bar"), double(:name => "bar.foo")]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a helper class, let us call it Clazz, and use that instead of hashes.

```
class Clazz < Struct.new(:name); end;

provider.api.release.rels[:assets].get.stub(:data).and_return([Clazz.new("name1"), Clazz.new("name2")])
```

Now you can use and call `name` as a method.